# how to add Dynamic Conditional Background Images in angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8

I am new to Angular (8). I am trying to add background image with condition. Please help me to sort it out. following is my code.

```html
<div class="kt-avatar__holder"
[ngStyle]="{'background-image': if addUser.value.attachmentURL? {{addTDAUser.value.userImage}} else'../assets/media/users/300_20.jpg'}">
  
Content

</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `[ngStyle]` like this

```
<div class="kt-avatar__holder" style="height: 200px; width: 200px;"
        [ngStyle]="{'background-image': addUser.value.attachmentURL ? 'url(' + addTDAUser.value.userImage + ')' : 'url(' + '../assets/media/users/300_20.jpg' + ')' }">
       Content
</div>
```

Comment: it's still not working just vanished all the below form field

Comment: Create a stackblitz example.

Comment: Its still not work but i found the solution now i am using static background image and for addTDAUser.value.userImage using <img src="addTDAUser.value.userImage ">

Vote Up thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

```html
<div class="event-thumbnail"
    [ngStyle]="{'background-image': item.logoURL ? 'url(' + item.logoURL + ')' : 'url(' + 'assets/img/default/event-1.png' + ')' }">
```

Comment: This answer could be greatly improved If you share why you think the code snippet posted solves the question.